# Weird flags in review queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-queue

I just saw some weird flags in the flag review queue -- see the circled description below. I saw a couple of these -- are they someone's weird idea of a custom flag reason, or a bug? This one is on a [perfectly good answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305306/asmack-muc-getmembers-forbidden-403-openfire/17355178#17355178) Note that the numbers themselves are [a clickable link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355134), unlike normal flag reasons.

[image]

Comment: It's an audit ;P

Comment: This is a "duplicate answers" flag. IIRC they're not supposed to be shown to 10k users. Also, the absence of the text "Duplicate answers: " is a concern.

Comment: @Manishearth How do you know it's a duplicate answers flag?

Comment: It is a “duplicate answer” flag, and I’m pretty sure they were always shown to 10k users, but with the text “duplicate answer” leading up to them. Anyways, filter the queue to “duplicate answers (auto)” and you’ll get proof =)

Comment: OK, thanks for info. So it sounds like the bug is that the text "Duplicate answer" is all of a sudden missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added "Duplicate answers: " to the start of these, going forward.

Will start in the next build.

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir!